# How can I reverse an accidental Gzip compression?

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, gzip

I am using Raspbian and had a folder full of images. I selected all of the images, right clicked them, and selected "Compress" so that I could put them in an archive to move to another computer. I selected archive type as "gz" and left "add archive extension to filename" checked. What was produced was a "[oneofthepicturefilenames].png.gz" which I moved to the other computer.

The problem is, when I open this .gz, I only see one png that is the size of the entire directory I compressed (1.4Gb). unfortunately, the source images were deleted, and I'm trying to figure out how to recover my images from this file as I assume their data is still there in some strange format. Any ideas?

The images aren't sensitive, so if anyone wants to take a look at what I've done, you can see the file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oaetaxcpx0balr7/img2019-03-29-18-23.png.gz?dl=0).

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ would be better places to ask this.

Comment: I disagree with @AlexK. because there is nothing raspberry-pi specific about this question.  But neither is it relevant here, because it's not related to software development. Probably best on https://superuser.com/.

Comment: Note that `gzip` is not an archive format: you cannot combine multiple files into a single `gzip` "archive" because there is no such thing; gzip only compresses single files. It is common to combine `tar` + `gzip` to create compressed archives.